# Rails using paper clip in json builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have attached image which is called icon it has three forms the original, medium & thumb.
I want to use the thumb URL instead of the original one in the jbuilder

This is the thumb declaration in the model

```
has_attached_file :icon, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

`:icon` in `index.json.jbuilder` here returns the url of the full image how can I modify it to return the thumb url

```
json.array!(@brands.visible) do |brand|
  json.extract! brand, :id, :name, :position, :visible, :permalink, :counter, :description, :icon
end
```

And Here is the action in the controller

```
  def index
    @brands = Brand.all.sorted
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `extract!`, as you need to pass an argument of `:thumb` to `icon`. You need to add the `icon` attribute independently:

```
json.array!(@brands.visible) do |brand|
  json.extract! brand, :id, :name, :position, :visible, :permalink, :counter, :description
  json.icon brand.icon.url(:thumb)
end
```